# Java 8 stream overhead in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, java-stream

I'm not an expert in Spark, and I'm using Spark to do some calculations.

```
    // [userId, lastPurchaseLevel]
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> lastPurchaseLevels = 
            levels.groupByKey()
            .join(purchases.groupByKey())
            .mapValues(t -> getLastPurchaseLevel(t));
```

And inside the **getLastPurchaseLevel()** function, I had such code:

```
private static Integer getLastPurchaseLevel(Tuple2<Iterable<SourceLevelRecord>, Iterable<PurchaseRecord>> t) {

....
final Comparator<PurchaseRecord> comp = (a, b) -> Long.compare(a.dateMsec, b.dateMsec);
PurchaseRecord latestPurchase = purchaseList.stream().max(comp).get();
```

But my boss told me not to use the **stream()**, he said:

> We better do the classic way because there are no CPU core remains to do the streaming -- all CPUs are used by Spark workers already.

I know the classic way is to iterate through and find the **max**, so **stream** will cause more CPU consumption or overhead than the classic way? Or is it only in these kind of Spark context?

Comment: There is a bit of extra overhead in streaming, but it won't take extra cores unless you explicitly parallelize it.

Comment: @shmosel For explicitly parallelize do you mean something like     **listA.stream().parallel().forEach(t->doSomething(t) );** ? Thank you.

Comment: Or `listA.parallelStream()`.

Comment: @shmosel So the conclusion is I'm safe here to use the **stream** ?

Comment: There is no relevant difference in what will happen, as streaming is a *concept*, there is no additional resource dedicated to “do the streaming”. In the end, the underlying code will loop over the elements and compare. So yes, it’s safe to use a stream. But you can always use `Collections.max(purchaseList, comp)` instead of looping manually or streaming (since 1.2). By the way, an alternative for creating the comparator is `Comparator.comparingLong(x -> x.dataMsec)` resp. `Comparator.comparingLong(PurchaseRecord::getDataMsec)`…

Comment: @Holger  Well thank you very much！

Comment: If you need to be sure, you need to measure the time the task takes with and without streams. On the computer and in the environment where it will run in production, or at least one that is very similar.

Comment: @OleV.V. Actually the time is almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We better do the classic way because there are no CPU core remains to do the streaming -- all CPUs are used by Spark workers already.

Your boss's idea: Spark already schedules the tasks to threads ( or cpu cores ), no need to do things concurrently inside single task.

> ... so stream will cause more CPU consumption or overhead than the classic way? Or is it only in these kind of Spark context?

Java stream is single threaded unless otherwise specified ( by calling Stream.parallel() method ). So as long as you don't parallelize the stream, your boss won't complain.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, since it's been a long time.